# How to assign a property of type Control in XAML - error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a WPF user control with a property of type Control, to associate it with another control (usually a textbox) that it will send key presses to. 
I can assign this property in XAML, and it compiles *and works* at runtime.

But the IDE shows an error "38 The method or operation is not implemented." on the TargetControl assignment.

```
<my:NumericButtonsControl 
 x:Name="NumericButtons" 
 TargetControl="{x:Reference Name=DataEntryTextBox}" />
```

The user control code in question looks like this:

```
public partial class NumericButtonsControl : UserControl
{
    private Control _TargetControl;

    public Control TargetControl
    {
        get 
        {
            return _TargetControl;
        }
        set
        {
            _TargetControl = value;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write a WPF application, you'd probably want to avoid using `x:Reference`, as it's a feature of XAML 2009 which is only available for loose XAML.

Alternatively, you can use binding and its `ElementName` property. But for that to work you'll need to make `TargetControl` a dependency property. Then it will look like this:

**C#**

```cs
public Control TargetControl
{
    get { return (Control)this.GetValue(TargetControlProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(TargetControlProperty, value); } 
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetControlProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TargetControl",
                                typeof(Control),
                                typeof(NumericButtonsControl),
                                new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

**XAML:**

```
<my:NumericButtonsControl 
    x:Name="NumericButtons" 
    TargetControl="{Binding ElementName=DataEntryTextBox}" />
```

Comment: Cool. That works. I couldn't figure out how to Google for this question. Guessed dependency properties were important, but I don't really see why... Thanks :)